# Register on('click') insight another on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have the folowing JavaScript code:

```
 ... .on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $el = $(this);
                var edit_url = $el.attr('href');
                var $comment_holder = $($el.closest('li'));
                var $comment_item = $comment_holder.children('.comments__item');
                var comment_text = $comment_item.find('.comments__text p').html();

                var $edit_form = $('.comments form').clone();
                $edit_form.attr('action', '#');
                $edit_form.find('.btn').removeClass('add-comment').addClass('edit-comment');
                $edit_form.find('textarea').val(comment_text);


                $comment_item.hide();
                $comment_holder.append($edit_form);

                $('.edit-comment').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formProps = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
                   $.post(edit_url, formProps)
                    .success(function() {
                        var new_comment_val =$edit_form.find('textarea').val();
                        $comment_item.find('.comments__text p').html(new_comment_val);
                       $comment_holder.html($comment_item);
                    });
                });
      });
```

So my question is: It is normal that I registered `on('click')` in another or not? Will be the embedded `on('click')` re-registered each time when I click on `'.edit'` element. This is a little bit uncleraly for me.

Comment: It will get re-registered everytime you click on edit

Comment: use delegated event handlers instead

Comment: @ArunPJohny, if I proper understand the docs https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ , I can to the event delegation because  `'.edit-comment'` is not children of `'.edit'`, or I ommit somethin?